# Jewish sources for Jerome on Daniel 11:34

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, commentaries, daniel-book-of, rome

[Jerome](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome), in his commentary on [Daniel 11:34](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.11.34?with=all&lang=bi), wrote (my translation from a Hebrew translation):

> "In defeat, they will receive a little help - there are among the Jews that relate this verse to Severus and his son Antoninus who greatly respected the Jews."

Jerome had learned Hebrew from Jews in the Land of Israel in the Amoraic period and had known some of the Amoraim. In general, he greatly respected the Jews he met with and brought several of their ideas in his commentary on the Bible.

I was wondering whether anyone knows of any midrash or early commentary (Rishonic and back) that brings this same idea that he heard from the Jews in his time?

Comment: Are you specifically after sources that concur with the quote you bring - Like the answer from @yih613? Or are you after other examples where Jerome cites something that is backed up by contemporary works?

Comment: @Dov no, just for this specific example. But what you brought in your now-deleted answer is interesting info nonetheless. :)

Comment: I mean, I wanted to see if this tradition was preserved also over the generations by us Jews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raava'd (אברהם בן דוד הלוי - הראב"ד הראשון) in his sefer kabala says this.

[image]

as does the אברבנל (מעיני הישועה- המעיין י"א)

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you!