# Digital text versions of Breslov sefarim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, breslov

I've come across some of [the many different PDFs available](http://breslovbooks.com/download-books.html) of Breslov sefarim on BreslovBooks.com, but I was wondering if there were versions available in plain text format so as to be able to copy and paste easily in Unicode/UTF-8.

Dose anyone know if there are available copies of:

- חיי מוהר"ן (Chayey Moharan)
- ליקוטי מוהר"ן (Likkutei Moharan)
- סיחות הר"ן (Sichos Haran)
- etc.

in a plain-text format?

Comment: One way to find plain text versions of things in PDF format is to type a random sentence of the book into google. Don't use the first sentence or a famous/popular one - use a random sentence from the middle of the book. Stick it in quotation marks if you need to (so google will look for the exact phrase). If it's online, google will find it.

Comment: see the links in this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23156/603

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OYW app has a bunch of them. ([iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onyourway-wblktk-bdrk-m-gr/id449507485?mt=8)|[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=OYW&hl=en)|[Web Browser](http://mobile.tora.ws/)), and http://breslev.eip.co.il/ has a couple of them.