# Happiness for a Bar Mitzvah

Tags: sources-mekorot, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, simchah-joy-happiness, acharonim

I heard in the name of the [Chasam Sofer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sofer) that the first mitzvah of a bar mitzvah boy is that of simcha (happiness). Does anyone know where I could find the original source of this?

I searched Google and found the following quote [here](http://www.beyondbt.com/2012/06/19/simcha-a-sign-of-the-times/):

> The Chasam Sofer (1762-1839) writes “the very first mitzvah one should be fulfilled by a bar mitzvah boy upon his reaching his 13th year is to rejoice and be happy to accept the mitzvahs of Hashem; for being b’simcha is a positive mitzvah in the Torah, i.e., to serve with joyousness and good-heartedness emanating from all the goodness which has been bestowed upon you.”

Comment: possibly relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18744/759

Comment: I have excepted this from www.dafnotes.com from the 1st page of the current Daf Yomi cycle:

the author of Chidushei HaRim zt”l explained simply: The mitzvah of kerias shema is the first mitzvah incumbent on a boy when he becomes an adult on the evening of his bar-mitzvah. It is therefore clear why Rebbe opened tractate Brachos with this mitzvah.

Comment: the first mitzva (of the 613) is actually shema. this is why it's the first mishna as the vilna gaon writes there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Double AA I found the source in Piskei T'shuvos footnote 12 which refers to the Chasam Sofer on the Torah in Parshas Vayechi, Divrei Hamaschil "VaYar Yosef".

Comment: Edited - You meant to say "Divrei Hamaschil" - words that begin, not "Divrei Hamaskil" - words that make you wiser. It's actually a clever typo, as the Chasam Sofer's commentary DOES make you wiser. But, I don't think that's what you meant, here ;-)

Comment: Divrei is a smichut, so it should either be dibur hamaschil or dvarmim hamaschliim