# Commentary of Rav Saadiah Gaon

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, saadya-gaon

Other than Tafsir Rasag, what else did Rav Saadiah Gaon write on Tanach? Did he write a full commentary on it? Can I find these writings online?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon#Works

Comment: [R. Petachia of Ratisbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petachiah_of_Regensburg) in describing what he saw in his travels in Bavel in the Twelfth Century writes: ובארץ בבל לומדים פירוש רבינו סעדיה **שעשה מכל הקרייה** ומששה סדרים. It seems like some of it must have been lost.

Comment: I think the Torat Chayim Chumash has his commentary translated (?) into Hebrew

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13284/is-there-a-mitzva-to-speak-loshon-kodesh/75792#comment221741_75792

Comment: https://mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/

Answer (score 2):

There is some question if Rav Saadya Gaon really authored some of the writings on Tanach attributed to him. The Chida in Shem HaGadolim writes  that he has seen the commentary (mostly an Arabic translation) on all of Chumash written by  Rav Saadya Gaon which is consistent with wherever he is quoted by the Even Ezra.

He also authenticates the existence of a commentary of RSG on Daniel and  Ezra.

As far as the other commentaries on Nach attributed to Rav Saady Gaon, like many others, the Chida questions the possibility of Rav Saadya Gaon having authored them when they seemingly  make references to Seforim that postdate him. In all his travels (where he came across many writing of earlier times that we don't have) he doesn't seem to have even seen any such commentary clearly authored by RSG himself.