# Shema pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, shema

I've heard that the proper way to say the Shema Israel is by pronouncing the final daleth (d) sound for a longer time.

1) Is this a real thing? What are the sources?
2)I find it near impossible to pronounce a long "d".

Comment: Check out [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60174/%D7%93-mi-yodeya-the-pronunciation) [two](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10250/how-do-you-extend-the-sound-of-a-daleth-in-shema) questions. I think the question in the first link and the answer of the second link answer your two-pronged question.

Comment: The daleth doesn't have a dagesh, so it's pronounced "th" as in "this".